# EMCLI command that will show targets that are not in a group

Tags: oracle, ems

Have been looking through the get_groups and get_group_members and am not seeing any way to find how to list targets that have not been assigned a group.

./emcli get_targets -targets -targes="host" -unamanged
./emcli get_group_members -name= (leaving name blank)